# MySQL - math operations between rows

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL 8 database table like this:

```
+-------+
| Total |
+-------+
| 100   |
+-------+
| 40    |
+-------+
```

I want to get the difference between the rows -> result = (row - (row + 1))
Before the math operation I always have only two rows.

My desired result is something like this:

```
+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
| 60     |
+--------+
```

What is the best way to do this?

I came up with something like this:

```
SELECT ABS( (a.total - LEAD(a.total,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY t.total) )) AS result FROM (...) a LIMIT 1
```

Before the math operation I always have only two rows.

Comment: for that you can use window functions, but to use them you need a column that defines the order

Comment: See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/  or similar.

Comment: It could be -60 or 60, depending on weather conditions.

Comment: what do you want if there are no rows, or one row, or more than two rows?

Comment: rows do not have any defined implicit order, so there is no such thing as "row + 1"; you need a separate column to define the order of rows, or you need a rule such as the higher number coming first

Comment: What's missing right now is a way to define the order for the rows. That is, which row relative to a given row, exactly, is "row + 1". Remember, databases do not have any concept and explicitly disclaim all responsibility for knowing any kind of natural order or insert order. In fact, they can even move rows around on disk or return different results for the same query from run to run if you don't define the order within the confines of the data itself.

Comment: Before the math operation I always have only two rows. I used ABS() function. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). I particularly never used but it seems to do the work.